# Mahout: Vectorizing a folder containing documents using java

Tags: java, hadoop, mahout

After a lot of googling , I'm afraid I can't find a way of converting a text files in a directory to mahout vector in an output directory, So I can run LDA clustering afrerwards.

All I was mannaged to find was dealing with linux shell scripts.

Beacause I'm using windows I can't run shell scripts, also, I would like to avoid using cygwin. So actualy , I can only use the java api.

I'm currntly using mahout 0.9 .

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [SequenceFilesFromDirectory](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/mahout/trunk/integration/src/main/java/org/apache/mahout/text/SequenceFilesFromDirectory.java) job from the Mahout-Integration package to create the sequence files from a directory.

You can then create Mahout sparse vectors using the [SparseVectorsFromSequenceFiles](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/mahout/trunk/mrlegacy/src/main/java/org/apache/mahout/vectorizer/SparseVectorsFromSequenceFiles.java) job from the Mahout-MapReduce-Legacy package (Mahout-Core package in 0.9).

These are the drivers for seqdirectory and seq2sparse respectively, the parameters for which can be found here: mahout.apache.org/users/basics/creating-vectors-from-text.html